# why do last 4 digits of any square can be equal only when all of them equal 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

From the statement below, how can the author say that "every natural number can be written in the form $50000k\pm r$ 
with $0\le r\le 25000$" .Is there a rule or theory about that, or It is just a counterexample?From all the numbers,why 50 000 and 25000?Can someone enlighten me? It's from the journal [Oblath's Problem](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Panaitopol/panaitopol41.tex)

Since every natural number can be written in the form $50000k\pm r$ 
with $0\le r\le 25000$, and 
$(50000k\pm r)^2\equiv r^2\pmod {100000}$, 
we compute $r^2$ for $r\le 25000$  and find that the last 4 digits of any square 
can be equal only when all of them equal 0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a general fact, known as "Euclidean division" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem)), that for any integers $a$ and $b$ (with $b\neq 0$), there are **unique** integers $k$ and $r$ such that 
$$a=bk+r\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 0\leq r<|b|$$
Usually, the number $r$ is referred to as the "remainder" of dividing $a$ by $b$. However, this theorem can be slightly modified ([see here in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Generalized_division_algorithms)) to say that there are **unique** integers $k$ and $r$ such that
$$a=bk+r\qquad\text{ and }\qquad -\left\lfloor {\frac {b}{2}}\right\rfloor \leq r<b-\left\lfloor {\frac {b}{2}}\right\rfloor$$
which, for the choice of $b=50000$, says that any integer $a$ can be written **uniquely** as $a=50000k+r$
with 
$$-25000\leq r<25000$$
Now, in the statement you cited, the author has just slightly removed the uniqueness, and instead made the weaker (but no less valid) statement that any $a$ can be written as $a=50000k+r$ with
$$-25000\leq r\leq 250000$$

Answer (score 0):

When last 2 digits are equal, the last digit can be only 4 ($12^2=144$). Just search a number which become ○○4444.  3rd digit of $ab12^2$ become 4b+1, this can't be 4. So such a number does not exist.